# Selecting elements from network with shortest path in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, routing, geometric-network

I have a network of vector elements (let´s say 70 elements) that are connected in each node. Actually, it is a pipe network built with the help of GHydraulics (http://epanet.de/ghydraulics/index.html.en).

I want to select the list of elements of the network layer using a shortest path tool like the one of road graph. The order of the list matters - it should follow the path.
Any clues?

Even the order could not be achieved; I tried to use spatial query with:

- source: network layer
- reference: shortest path layer
- where features: overlaps

There should be at least 20 elements from source on the shortest path, but it does not select anything. With a buffer it works, but I have to review the buffer distance to check that no small falls within the buffer by mistake.